# FakeItEasy argument constraint being evaluated as null outside of lambda

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd, fakeiteasy

Using FakeItEasy, I have a setup similar to the one below in one of my tests, and the `CallTo` assertion at the bottom is failing when setup like this.

```
var fakedTool = A.Fake<ITool>();

var concreteUnderTest = new Concrete(fakedTool);

concreteUnderTest.doSomething();

var fooConstraint = A<Foo>.That.Matches(f => f.Name.Equals('Alice'));
var barConstraint = A<Bar>.Ignored;

A.CallTo(() => fakedTool.ObservedFunction(fooConstraint , barConstraint))
    .MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

I have placed a breakpoint directly above the `CallTo` line, and the values of `fooConstraint` and `barConstraint` are both `null`.

When I set the assertion up like this, however, it passes:

```
A.CallTo(() =>
    fakedTool.ObservedFunction(
        A<Foo>.That.Matches(f => f.Name.Equals('Alice')),
        A<Bar>.Ignored
    )
).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

What is causing this behaviour? Is it intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behaviour. You can see the section [**Always place `Ignored` and `That` inside `A.CallTo`**](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/argument-constraints/#always-place-ignored-and-that-inside-acallto) in the docs.

As of FakeItEasy 2.0.0, [FakeItEasy will throw an exception when they're stored as variables and invoked](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/559), rather than failing quietly by being null.

Comment: You might as well accept the answer, to signal to readers that it's correct.

Comment: @BlairConrad SO prevents accepting your own answer for 2 days - I will accept in then :)

Comment: Ah. I was not aware. Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: No problem @BlairConrad! I didn't know until I tried to click accept yesterday :P